# Pythonic way of defining the function

Tags: python

A homework assignment asks us to write some functions, namely `orSearch` and `andSearch` .

```
"""
Input: an inverse index, as created by makeInverseIndex, and a list of words to query
Output: the set of document ids that contain _any_ of the specified words
Feel free to use a loop instead of a comprehension.

>>> idx = makeInverseIndex(['Johann Sebastian Bach', 'Johannes Brahms', 'Johann Strauss the Younger', 'Johann Strauss the Elder', ' Johann Christian Bach',  'Carl Philipp Emanuel Bach'])
>>> orSearch(idx, ['Bach','the'])
{0, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> orSearch(idx, ['Johann', 'Carl'])
{0, 2, 3, 4, 5}
"""
```

Given above is the documentation of `orSearch` similarly in `andSearch` we return only those set of docs which contains all instances of the query list.

We can assume that the inverse index has already been provided. An example of an inverse index for `['hello world','hello','hello cat','hellolot of cats']` is `{'hello': {0, 1, 2}, 'cat': {2}, 'of': {3}, 'world': {0}, 'cats': {3}, 'hellolot': {3}}`

So my question is, I was able to write a single line comprehension for the `orSearch` method given by

```
def orSearch(inverseIndex, query):
    return {index for word in query if word in inverseIndex.keys() for index in inverseIndex[word]}
```

But I am unable to think of the most pythonic way of writing `andSearch`. I have written the following code, it works but I guess it is not that pythonic

```
def andSearch(inverseIndex, query):
    if len(query) != 0:
        result = inverseIndex[query[0]]
    else:
        result = set()

    for word in query:
        if word in inverseIndex.keys():
            result = result & inverseIndex[word]

    return result
```

Any suggestions on more compact code for `andSearch` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite `orSearch()` to use `any()` to find any of the terms, and then derive `andSearch()` by modifying your solution to use `all()` instead to find all of the terms.

Comment: I am new to python , I haven't used `any` and `all`. I read about them, but I am unable to use them in the context .

Answer (score 1):

More Pythonic way to write **andSerch()** will be:

```
from functools import reduce
def andSearch(inverseIndex, query):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, [(inverseIndex[key]) for key in query])
```

Here we used reduce function to aggregate results of transitional calculations.

Also it may be useful to check if all items of **query** are in **inverseIndex**. Then our function will look like

```
from functools import reduce
def andSearch(inverseIndex, query):
    if set(query) < set(inverseIndex.keys()):
        return reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, [(inverseIndex[key]) for key in query])
    else:
        return False # or what ever is meaningful to return
```